# JS/Regex matching way more than it should

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a piece of regex parsing a form from text, which(regex) goes `/\[\[(?:.*(?:(?:(?:_:v=(.*))|o|x):s=(\d))|(h=(\d)))?\]\]/g`, and is supposed to match (and later on used on each match without the /g to group) information which is in the form of `[[((o|x|_v:=*answer*):s=*points*)|(h=*points*)]]`

real example of the information:

```
"https://asiointi.maanmittauslaitos.fi/karttapaikka/Etsi Karttapaikka-
palvelusta Forssan maastokartta ja tee tehtävät (voi tehdä pareittain). 
Klikkaa + ja - näppäimiä, kun etsit paikkojen nimiä ja karttamerkkejä.1. 
Etsi Pyhäjärven Similänlahti.a) Millaista metsää sen rannalla on? 
[[_:v=lehtimetsä:s=1:t=]]b) Mitä on kohdassa, jossa lukee Urpola? 
[[_:v=pelto:s=1:t=]]2. Kuinka korkea on Korkeavahan korkein kohta? 
[[_:v=135:s=1:t=]] metriä.3. Kuinka pitkä matka on Kuhalan koululta 
linnuntietä (lähtö yläkoulun pihalta, klikkaa viivoitin-kuvaketta, alku- 
ja loppupiste kaksoisklikkaus, tyhjennä kartta mittausten välillä)a) 
Keskurille?[[o:s=0]] 500 m[[o:s=0]] 600 m[[o:s=0]] 700 m[[o:s=0]] 800 
m[[o:s=1]] 900 mb) Tölölle?[[o:s=0]] 500 m[[o:s=0]] 600 m[[o:s=1]] 700 
m[[o:s=0]] 800 m[[o:s=0]] 900 m4. Lisää kartalle oma merkintä. Merkitse 
kotitalosi otsikolla esim. Kullervon koti."
```

It matches the entire thing from the first [[ to the last ]], even though it's supposed to be lazy. Why is this?

Edit: What I want

I want it to give me a clean list of matches like

```
[[_:v=lehtimetsä:s=1:t=]]
[[_:v=pelto:s=1:t=]]
[[_v:=135:s=1:t=]]
[[o:s=0]]
...
```

Comment: Why do you think `(.*)` is "supposed to be lazy" ?

Comment: I mean there is a ? on the end of the group grouping the whole thing so it should be

Comment: A ? after a group doesn't make it lazy but optional

Comment: RegExr identifies it as lazy, not optional. If I place a ? in fornt of (.*) it identifies as optional

Comment: Not in front. If you want a lazy matching of the content change `(.*)` to `(.*?)`.

Comment: that isn't waht i want though. I should have explained it better

Comment: hard to make it clear in comments too so I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

`/\[\[(?:[ox]:|_:v=)[^\]]+\]\]/gi`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Ke8Uj/1/)**

**Result:**

```
Match 1
Full match  285-310 `[[_:v=lehtimetsä:s=1:t=]]`
Match 2
Full match  352-372 `[[_:v=pelto:s=1:t=]]`
Match 3
Full match  420-438 `[[_:v=135:s=1:t=]]`
Match 4
Full match  644-653 `[[o:s=0]]`
Match 5
Full match  659-668 `[[o:s=0]]`
Match 6
Full match  674-683 `[[o:s=0]]`
Match 7
Full match  689-698 `[[o:s=0]]`
Match 8
Full match  705-714 `[[o:s=1]]`
Match 9
Full match  731-740 `[[o:s=0]]`
Match 10
Full match  746-755 `[[o:s=0]]`
Match 11
Full match  761-770 `[[o:s=1]]`
Match 12
Full match  777-786 `[[o:s=0]]`
Match 13
Full match  792-801 `[[o:s=0]]`
```

**Explained:**

```
\[\[        # Literal '[[' (must be scaped since [] are used for character classes)
(?:         # 2 options (separated by |)
    [ox]:   # Option1: Either 'o' or 'x' character followed by ':'
   |_:v=    # Option2: Literal '_:v='
)
[^\]]+      # Any non-']' character repeated 1 or more times
\]\]        # Literal ']]'
```

Comment: What magic is this? Run me trough the regex please. But thanks, I'll test it and then select this

Comment: I added the explanation :)

Comment: thanks! took me some time as i had my laptop in for some repairs but i chose this

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want this:

```js
var s = document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, "");
var matches = s.match(/\[\[((_:v=[^:\]]+)|o|x):s=(\d)(:t=\d?)?\]\]/g);
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<pre>
https://asiointi.maanmittauslaitos.fi/karttapaikka/Etsi Karttapaikka-
palvelusta Forssan maastokartta ja tee tehtävät (voi tehdä pareittain). 
Klikkaa + ja - näppäimiä, kun etsit paikkojen nimiä ja karttamerkkejä.1. 
Etsi Pyhäjärven Similänlahti.a) Millaista metsää sen rannalla on? 
[[_:v=lehtimetsä:s=1:t=]]b) Mitä on kohdassa, jossa lukee Urpola? 
[[_:v=pelto:s=1:t=]]2. Kuinka korkea on Korkeavahan korkein kohta? 
[[_:v=135:s=1:t=]] metriä.3. Kuinka pitkä matka on Kuhalan koululta 
linnuntietä (lähtö yläkoulun pihalta, klikkaa viivoitin-kuvaketta, alku- 
ja loppupiste kaksoisklikkaus, tyhjennä kartta mittausten välillä)a) 
Keskurille?[[o:s=0]] 500 m[[o:s=0]] 600 m[[o:s=0]] 700 m[[o:s=0]] 800 
m[[o:s=1]] 900 mb) Tölölle?[[o:s=0]] 500 m[[o:s=0]] 600 m[[o:s=1]] 700 
m[[o:s=0]] 800 m[[o:s=0]] 900 m4. Lisää kartalle oma merkintä. Merkitse 
kotitalosi otsikolla esim. Kullervon koti.
</pre>
```